# Setting table column width with textwidth

Tags: tables

I wanted to set the size of columns relative to the `textwidth` of the paper layout. However I got unexpected result:

[image]

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|}
     \hline a & b & c & d
  \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

    \begin{document}   
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{4pt}\\
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                |p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                |p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
                |p{0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
     \hline a & b & c & d
  \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Width `p{<width>` is determined the width of content of cell, so the width of column actually is `<width> + 2\tabcolsep`. For fit of table in width of text, you should subtract 2\tabcolsep from width goven i `p{...}`. This enable  package `calc`.

[image]

**Edit:** In rush I forgot that cell's border lines has some width too. There is, as pointed Heiko Oberdiek in his comments two cases:
- without use of package `array`, they are not to be considered (as it is shown in above MWE
- with use of `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{calc}

    \begin{document}
```

they should be considered as follows for given example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth}
                |p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth}
                |p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth}
                |p{0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep - 1.25\arrayrulewidth}|}
p{0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep - 0.5\arrayrulewidth}
```

with assumption that fifth vertical line is evenly distributed between columns. In this case we obtain:

[image]

and without considering of the table vertical lines width:

[image]

I correct the above code (again) accordingly.

Comment: That's still going to be too wide, by `5\arrayrulewidth`.

Comment: @Mico, in rush I forgot on lthe lines ..., they are not zero width! I will correct my answer. Thank you to point me.

Comment: Since there are 5 vertical bars (each of width `\arrayrulewidth`) and 4 columns, you need to subtract `1.25\arrayrulewidth`, right?

Comment: @Mico Package `array` makes the difference. The vertical lines do not contribute to the width of the table without package `array`. If package `array` is loaded (often indirectly by other packages like `tabularx`), then the vertical lines contribute to the width and `\arrayrulewidth` needs to be taken into account.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - I'd forgotten about the effects that loading the `array` package has on length calculations.

Answer (score 4):

The *total* width of your `tabular` environment is `\textwidth` plus `8\tabcolsep` -- because whitespace in the amount of `\tabcolsep` (default value: `6pt`) is inserted to the left and right of each column) -- plus `5\arrayrulewidth` -- since there are 5 vertical bars.

You could either subtract `2\tabcolsep+1.25\arrayrulewidth` from each of the four pre-specified column widths, or you could use a `tabularx` environment and let LaTeX do the width calculations for you.

Note that if you subtract equal amounts from all four columns, the *usable* amount of space in the fourth column is going to be less than 1/3 of the amount of space in the first three. In contrast, the `tabularx`-based approach will give you usable amounts of space with proportions 3:3:3:1 -- which are, of course, also the proportions in your original example. Which method is "better" depends on your use case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}

\newlength\mylena % for width of first three columns
\setlength\mylena{0.3\textwidth}
\addtolength\mylena{-2\tabcolsep}
\addtolength\mylena{-1.25\arrayrulewidth}

\newlength\mylenb % for width of fourth column
\setlength\mylenb{0.1\textwidth}
\addtolength\mylenb{-2\tabcolsep}
\addtolength\mylenb{-1.25\arrayrulewidth}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{\mylena}|p{\mylena}|p{\mylena}|p{\mylenb}|}
     \hline a & b & c & d
  \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\noindent
%% Why "1.2" and "0.4"? Because 3*1.2 + 0.4 = 4.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{3}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|} >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}X|}
     \hline a & b & c & d
  \\ \hline 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```